# Maps not working in the android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying the Google maps API example, but when I run the code emulator gives the error "The Application has stopped unexpectedly". I have put down the Logcat details below and also attached [the screenshot of the error](https://picasaweb.google.com/102118480344538129464/DropBox?authkey=Gv1sRgCKCImtiT-6nFZg#5577165216066241730).

---

```
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develope.GoogleMaps/net.learn2develope.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at net.learn2develope.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:11)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     ... 11 more
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     ... 21 more
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
02-24 13:31:42.841: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676):     ... 24 more
```

---

Answer (score 0):

What's the class where you're using it? Does that class extend `MapActivity` ?

According to your errors, it should.

Comment: Yes it extends the Map Activity.